# Paperclip image inside link_to => undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for #<Design:0x00000002dfa5f0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
<% if design.avatar.file? %>
    <%= link_to image_tag design.avatar.url(:thumb), design %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to image, design %>
<% end%>
```

And i get this error:

```
undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for #<Design:0x00000002dfa5f0>
```

But then, if I remove the design part from first link, leaving code like this:

```
<% if design.avatar.file? %>
    <%= link_to image_tag design.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to image, design %>
<% end%>
```

It works! Obviously with an empty link in the first place, but renders the page.

The image variable is defined in application_helper.rb as follows:

```
def image
    image = image_tag("image.jpg", :alt => %(No image available), :class => "round")
end
```

I'm obviously missing something here...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should at least put parentheses around your inner method call:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(design.avatar.url(:thumb)), design %>
```

because ruby interprets `design` as second argument to `image_tag`, and `image_tag` expects a hash there, which it tries to normalize (with `symbolize_keys!`)

Comment: I tried that before and did not work, but with your answer I've realized I left a whitespace after image_tag... Thanks!